# "this" avaialable but "this.state" not available

Tags: reactjs, console.log

```
componentDidMount : function()
{
    console.log(this);//1
    console.log(this.state);//2
}
```

line 1 shows all details, uncluding all state variables but line 2 gives empty object. Why? How do i access the state variables or other functions?

Comment: if you didn't initialize you component with any state. `this.state` is expected to be an empty object. what do you mean by `other functions`

Comment: Browsers' console is lazy so it dereferences object references lazily on your demand. To make sure the actual contents of the `this` reference - use debugger and check it while the engine is broken.

Comment: @xiaofan2406 : I meant the functions defined in the class.

Answer (score 1):

That's expected because state needs to be defined before using. The common way with ES6 classes is to define initial state from within constructor, a such:

```
class MyCmp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super(); // don't forget to call superclass constructor
        this.state = {foo: 1};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this);//1
        console.log(this.state);//2
    }
}
```

If you use proposal-grade JavaScript (e.g. if you have stage-0 or some other stage number as a profile in your Babel configuration), then you can define it as a class property too:

```
class MyCmp extends React.Component {
    state = {
        foo: 1
    };

    componentDidMount : function() {
        console.log(this);//1
        console.log(this.state);//2
    }
}
```

If you don't use ES6 classes, you would do something like:

```
var MyCmp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            foo: 1
        }
    },
    componentDidMount : function() {
        console.log(this);//1
        console.log(this.state);//2
    }
}
```

I hope that helped. Enjoy React!

Comment: if you're not using ES6 (I think?) you would set the `getInitialState' property of your component: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: Absolutely true, I didn't catch that immediately. Thanks @Fizz, I updated my answer.

Comment: I'm using 0.13 version.. not ES6.. n I've used getInitialState to update all components.